# Select Menu - Onclick Popup Window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML select menu, with a few options with links. When I click on an option, it opens the link (using the following javascript):

```
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore)
{
    eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
    if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
```

Which uses this html select menu:

```
<select name="actions" id="actions" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value="./external_link.html">External Link</option>
<option value="./external_link2.html">External Link2</option>
</select>
```

Now, my question: how can I make it so if the select menu is like this (notice there is a popup window link), to pop open a small window if the popup window option is clicked?

```
<select name="actions" id="actions" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value="./external_link.html">External Link</option>
<option value="./popup_window.html">Popup Window</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will popup the link if the text of the selection starts with ***Pop***

```
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore) {
  var target = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].text.indexOf('Pop')==0)?"_blank":"_"+targ; 
  window.open(selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value,target);
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
```

with size:

```
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore) {
  var pop = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].text.indexOf('Pop')==0);
  var parms = (pop)?"width=500,height=500":""; 
  var target =(pop)?"_blank":"_"+targ;
  window.open(selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value,target,parms);
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
```

With target in the options:

```
function popOrNot(selObj,restore) {
  var parms = "width=500,height=500"; 
  var opt = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value.split(':');
  var target =opt[0];
  var loc = opt[1];
  window.open(loc,target,parms);
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}

<select name="actions" id="actions" onchange="popOrNot(this,0)">
<option value="_parent:./external_link.html">External Link</option>
<option value="_blank:./popup_window.html">Popup Window</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I only need one of the links to open in a popup window. The others to open in a new browser window like normal. How can I achieve this?

Comment: see my changes. parent should be _parent to open in same window so I add the _ in front.

Comment: How can I just use one selection, but multiple options? One option to open in a blank window. Another option to open in a popup window.

Comment: Like that - if your text starts with Pop it will pop. Alternative is to add the target in the select. See my update in a minute

Comment: Okay, I tried it, but it's not working. When I click the popup window option, it doesn't popup anything, and vice-versa.

Comment: I had a pop left over in the last example. Try again